# Why are my Framework tests NOT running on my .Net Standard project, but .Net Core tests will, in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, nunit

We have built a .Net Standard project. As such, we want to make sure it runs in .Net Core and .Net Framework.  I have built out both suites of NUnit tests.  However, the .Net Framework tests just stopped running. When I try to run one, it compiles, goes through the motions, then returns "0 of 0 tests run" with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my NUnit3TestAdapter to 4.4.2 fixed the problem.